# Unable to edit data in ArcSDE geodatabase

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, editing, versioning

I'm dealing for the first time with an ArcSDE geodatabase.

I can't edit my data in ArcMap, most probably because I've already "registered as versioned" my feature dataset. I did use "Unregister as versioned" from ArcCatalog, but still can't edit my data and then I got some "schema lock error".

Do you have any clues?

I'm the only user of the geodatabase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can edit non versioned data too. In Editor Options dialog, select Versioning tab and unchec "Edit a version..." checkbox. Then start editing.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, I wasn't able to "register as versioned" my feature dataset because I had a map service which was using the database. Stopped the map service, and everything works fine.
@Artwork21 was right in their comment.

Answer (score 2):

If you have not set permissions to edit, you need to go into ArcCatalog and right click on the Database or each dataset and select permissions. Or you can use another database manager if you have one and make sure you are in the editing group or your username has permissions to edit,